# Can someone decipher the use of square brackets in this problem?

Tags: notation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

In order not to complicate, I'll not state the full problem statement, just the part that needs to be proven.
We should prove that $x< [1-(\frac{2}{3})^n]$ , for natural $n > 0$.

In the solution, they state that the following is true:

$2*[1-(\frac{2}{3})^{n-1}]+1 = 3*[1-(\frac{2}{3})^{n}]$

My guess is that this is the ceiling function,.

Comment: No special meaning here, the different brackets are only used to emphasize the nesting. It is the same as $2*\left(1-(\frac{2}{3})^{n-1}\right)+1 = 3*\left(1-(\frac{2}{3})^{n}\right)$

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, didn't even assume it could be the standard brackets. They usually never use different notation for normal brackets here...

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3232472/42969

Answer (score 1):

The square brackets are standard parentheses. The equality can be proved via the following series of operations:
$$
2\cdot\left[1 - \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n-1}\right] + 1 = 2 + 1 - 2\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n-1} = 3 - \frac{2^n}{3^{n-1}} = 3 - 3\frac{2^n}{3^{n}} = 3\left[1 - \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n}\right]
$$

Comment: Thanks, didn't even assume it could be the standard brackets. They usually never use different notation for normal brackets here...